# Replace relative URL from Facebook Feed

Tags: javascript, rss

I have a page that is pulling in a Facebook RSS feed. Unfortunately, the feed contains both relative and absolute paths. I want to give users the ability to click on any given story and read it on Facebook. One of the generated links is relative, so what should be:

`http://www.facebook.com/ShannonBaumGraphics/photos/a.253345034707618.56302.102938249748298/805807439461372/?type=1`

is converted to

`http://www.shannonbaumsigns.com/ShannonBaumGraphics/photos/a.253345034707618.56302.102938249748298/805807439461372/?type=1&relevant_count=1`

I tried the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.onload = function() { 
  var aEls = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); 
  for (var i = 0, aEl; aEl = aEls[i]; i++) { 
    aEl.href = aEl.href.replace("/ShannonBaumGraphics/photos/","http://www.facebook.com/ShannonBaumGraphics/photos/");  
  } 
}; 
</script>
```

But ended up with

`http://www.shannonbaumsigns.comhttp//www.facebook.com/ShannonBaumGraphics/photos/a.253345034707618.56302.102938249748298/805807439461372/?type=1&relevant_count=1`

I know it's something simple, but I'm not strong enough with Javascript to pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
aaEl.href = aEl.href.replace('http://www.shannonbaumsigns.com/ShannonBaumGraphics/photos/','http://www.facebook.com/ShannonBaumGraphics/photos/');  

// http://www.facebook.com/ShannonBaumGraphics/photos/a.253345034707618.56302.102938249748298/805807439461372/?type=1&relevant_count=1
```

Comment: If I do that, it will replace all the links on the page with links to Facebook, yes? I just need to replace those specific links.

Comment: then append `/ShannonBaumGraphics/photos/`? see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

you can simply assigning new url.try using this :

```
 aEl.href ="http://www.facebook.com/ShannonBaumGraphics/photos/";
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. It pointed me in the right direction. Part of the problem is that the site uses multiple domain names (I should have mentioned that). So I added some PHP to grab the domain name to search for the address, and then replaced it with the Facebook link.

Here's what it looks like now:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.onload = function() { 
  var aEls = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); 
  for (var i = 0, aEl; aEl = aEls[i]; i++) { 
    aEl.href = aEl.href.replace("<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>/ShannonBaumGraphics/photos/","www.facebook.com/ShannonBaumGraphics/photos/");  
  } 
}; 
</script>
```

Maybe there are better approaches, but this seems to work.